# Validating and Displaying database info from Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm starting to learn how to use Xamarin.Forms for app development. I'm making a simple app that only consists of a sign up, sign in and a page displaying the corresponding info when you sign in.

However, I'm running into some issues so far, mainly data validation. Why is it so complex in XAML? in HTML, you can just set the property "required", whereas every solution I've seen for XF that even claims to be "simple" consists of sometimes hundreds of lines of code.

After, data validation, I also want to make sure that the app won't let me save information if there's already an user registered with that email address. Lastly, I want to output an user's information once they log in.

My app consists of 3 views: SignUpPage, LoginPage and HomePage. Upon successful authentication, the user is taken to HomePage.

I'm using SQLite to handle the DB, with a single table RegUserTable.cs

This is the RegistrationPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using SQLite;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UNEDProFinal.Tables;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;



namespace UNEDProFinal.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class RegistrationPage : ContentPage
    {
        public RegistrationPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void Handle_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dbpath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "UserDatabase.db");
            var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbpath);
            db.CreateTable<RegUserTables>();

            var ChosenDate = EntryUserDOB.ToString();


            if (EntryUserPassword.Text != ConfirmEntryUserPassword.Text)
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    var passError = await this.DisplayAlert("Las contraseñas no concuerdan", "Error", "Intentarlo de Nuevo", "Salir");
                    if (passError)
                        await Navigation.PushAsync(new RegistrationPage());
                    else
                    {
                        await Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage());
                    }
                });
            }

            else
            {

                var item = new RegUserTables()
                {
                    UserName = EntryUserName.Text,
                    Password = EntryUserPassword.Text,
                    Email = EntryUserEmail.Text,
                    PhoneNumber = EntryUserPhoneNumber.Text,
                    UserFirstSurname = EntryUserFirstSurname.Text,
                    UserLastSurname = EntryUserLastSurname.Text,
                    UserDOB = ChosenDate
                };

                db.Insert(item);
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    var result = await this.DisplayAlert("Felicidades", "Usuario Registrado", "Continuar", "Salir");
                    if (result)
                        await Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage());
                });
            }
        }
    }



}
```

And the RegistrationPage.Xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="UNEDProFinal.Views.RegistrationPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout>
                <Grid Margin="20,0,0,0" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0">
                        <Entry Placeholder="Nombre" FontSize="16" x:Name="EntryUserName"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
                        <Entry Placeholder="Primer Apellido" FontSize="16" x:Name="EntryUserFirstSurname"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="2">
                        <Entry Placeholder="Segundo Apellido" FontSize="16" x:Name="EntryUserLastSurname"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="3">
                        <DatePicker  FontSize="16" Format="D" x:Name="EntryUserDOB"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="4">
                        <Entry Placeholder="Email" FontSize="16" x:Name="EntryUserEmail"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="5">
                        <Entry Placeholder="Número teléfonico" FontSize="16" x:Name="EntryUserPhoneNumber"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="6">
                        <Entry Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True" FontSize="16" x:Name="EntryUserPassword"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="7">
                        <Entry Placeholder="Confirm Password" IsPassword="True" FontSize="16" x:Name="ConfirmEntryUserPassword"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="8">
                        <Button Text="Register" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Blue" Clicked="Handle_Clicked"/>
                    </StackLayout>

                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>    
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

And I want to output the information the user entered once he logs in on HomePage.Xaml, which hasn't got anything on it so far.

Lastly, here's the table

```
using System;
namespace UNEDProFinal.Tables
{
    public class RegUserTables
    {
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string UserFirstSurname { get; set; }
        public string UserLastSurname { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string UserDOB { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I'd also like to know...with my current logic for saving information, is the database actually relating the entered information to a specific user? Or would it just be throwing random information?

Comment: You can use the `[Required]` attribute. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1274851/Xamarin-Forms-Validations-made-simple

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: @Jason There's 2 very clear questions there: I'd like to find a simple way to validate information in xamarin.forms, and I'd like to find a way to display that saved information in a page of the app.

No offense but, if the solution to validate has 7 steps to it, it's probably not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like to find a simple way to validate information in
>   xamarin.forms

You can write your own Validation by using [behaviors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/attached) in Xamarin.forms. For example:

```
public class PasswordValidationBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
{
    const string passwordRegex = @"^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,}$";

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry bindable)
    {
        bindable.TextChanged += HandleTextChanged;
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
    }

    void HandleTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool IsValid = false;
        IsValid = (Regex.IsMatch(e.NewTextValue, passwordRegex));
        ((Entry)sender).TextColor = IsValid ? Color.Default : Color.Red;
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry bindable)
    {
        bindable.TextChanged -= HandleTextChanged;
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
    }
}
```

You can also have e-`mailValidationBehavior`, `PhoneNumberValidationBehavior` and etc. Then add those Validations to Corresponding `Entry` and reuse these `Validations` in different Entry:

```
<Entry Placeholder="Enter a PassWord">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
        <local:PasswordValidationBehavior />
    </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
```

Here are some blogs you can read: [input-validation-in-xamarin-forms-behaviors](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/input-validation-in-xamarin-forms-behaviors/) and [custom-entry-validation-in-xamarin-forms](https://xamgirl.com/custom-entry-validation-in-xamarin-forms/)

> I'd like to find a way to display that saved information in a page of
>   the app.

Since you have saved information in the local DB, you can query personal info by specific UserId from DB and then show them in the Page with [Data-binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/) or other ways you want. Feel free to ask me any question.

Refer : [data-bindings-to-mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm)

Comment: Thank you. Can I use data binding with my setup? I don't think the tutorial I was following was using databinding, so I'm afraid about having to start over again from scratch.

Additionally, is validating also good for checking, for example, if there's already a given email in the database and not allow its storage if thats the case?

Comment: @Dasphillipbrau You can use data binding with setup to show/update values. Follow the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/) is also a good way to learn Xamarin.Forms. You should always validate the value before store it to the database. If it already exist, when you read it and find it is invalid, you can ask user to update it and then update it in your local database.